Extracting Graph[] data from a dxf file
I have created a graph in a CAD application and saved it in dxf format.
I am trying to solve a rather complicated graph with nearly a hundred vertices.  That's a lot of edge data to manually type into Graph[]
To visualize the graph  I constructed it in a CAD application and saved it in DXF format.  I then imported the DXF into Mathematica.  MMatica shows the image from the file but it is not clear from the help entry on DXF how to reference individual elements of the image, i.e. the edges making up the graph.
I thought it would be a simple problem but a couple hours of prowling for details on DXF format and reading digging through the MMatica docs left me without a simple solution.  Digging through the DXF file with a text editor and while reading through the format definitions left me with no clear idea how to extract the line data manually.
Is there a simple way to extract the line/edge data, either from the source file or from the imported data, to create a Graph[]?
If that's not enough information to garner a hint or two then I have no idea what better description of my question I can offer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check this list of "dxf graph" posts. Your question might be a duplicate of this answer about converting DXG edges to a Mathematica graph.
